# how to setup VMAC on verifone vx520?

Tags: point-of-sale, verifone

I want to run VMAC application on my verifone vx520. What should i do?
I want to use ethernet port for sending and receiving data by running VAMC.
I don't know how to run VMAC on it and how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first thing you will need to do is (unsurprisingly) to obtain a copy of VMAC.  This can be had at VeriFone's [DevNet](http://www.verifonedevnet.com) site (you will need to have an account).  While you are there, download the "Verix eVo Multi-App Conductor Programmers Guide"--you'll need that to figure out how to use VMAC's various APIs, etc. later.

After you have downloaded, you will need to install it to your computer (setup.exe).  The reason for this is to set environment variables and place files on your computer, both of which will allow you to develop against the VMAC libraries.  Note that if you are not developing on that machine, but rather you are just using it to put VMAC on to a terminal, I don't think installation is required.

For eVo terminals (like the 520) there's one more step you have to take-you must sign the VMAC files before you can download them to your terminal.  VeriFone has provided a .bat file that will do this for you.  After you have inserted your file signing card and logged into FST (file signing tool), then just run the .bat file under \output\rv\core\files.

**TIP 1:** Before you do the file sign, make a copy of the  folder.  That way, if something goes wrong during the install, you can easily revert.

**TIP 2:** If you want to have a version of VMAC that includes the network control panel (NCP), then you'll need to modify the `VMACIF.INS` files that is loaded into GID 1 RAM.  To do this, remove the LATENT and LATENTKEY keys and save the file. I believe you will need to resign after doing this (not certain).  I recommend have an NCP and a non-NCP version of VMAC to download which means you may want 2 copies of the  folder, anyway. (There may be a better way, but that's how I do it).